# How to read file (Metro/WinRT)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm quite astounded by the apparent complexity of this seemingly simple task. I know that I have to use the `StorageFile` class, and I've found this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150593.aspx), but I just want to read one single file, to which I know the path, and read it's data as text into a string.

From what I've been able to gather, to read a file with `StorageFile`, I have to go through a bunch of interfaces; `IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>` and `IAsyncOperationCompletedHandler`.

There must be a better (simpler) way. Something like:

```
using (StorageFile sf = StorageFile.OpenAsync("myFile.txt"))
{
    string line = sf.ReadLine();
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but maybe I've missed something, or someone could explain to me how to read a file in a different way?

Comment: I think the "Windows-8" and "Microsoft-metro" and "Winrt" tags are too subtle. ;) Might want to edit your question to say NOTE: THIS IS FOR WINDOWS METRO!

Comment: @Matthew Watson Yeah, thanks. I should probably have realized there would be an immediate rush to get reputation with a title like that. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This web page might be helpful: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html

Relevant code:

```
public string CurrentFileBuffer
{
    get; private set;
}

public async void ReadTextFile(string Path)
{
    var folder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(Path);
    var read = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    CurrentFileBuffer = read;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, finally someone actually read my question. This was giving me a really hard time. If you'd be so inclined, you could copy some of the code from that link to help future visitors.

Comment: I would, but bizarrely, the code is in a bitmap rather than selectable text. :(

Comment: This is a great help. I've been stumble for couple of days looking for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[Windows.Storage.FileIO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.aspx) has a bunch of helper/utility methods that do the job in a single line of code rather than using StorageIO interfaces and classes.

e.g.

```
ReadLineAsync()
ReadTextAsync()
WriteLineAsync()
WriteTextAsync()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get your file by using this:

```
StorageFile file3 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"C:\myFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FileIO` class like so.

```
public async void Read(IStorageFile file)
{
    var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);

}
```