# File IO in Windows 8

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-8, microsoft-metro, storage

I have been trying to read a file, and calculate the hash of the contents to find duplicates. The problem is that in `Windows 8` (or `WinRT` or windows store application or however it is called, I'm completely confused), `System.IO` has been replaced with `Windows.Storage`, which behaves differently, and is very confusing. The official documentation is not useful at all.

First I need to get a StorageFile object, which in my case, I get from browsing a folder from a file picker:

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
var folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
```

Now in files I have the list of files I need to index. Next, I need to open that file:

```
foreach (StorageFile file in files)
{
    var filestream = file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
```

Now is the most confusing part: getting the data from the file. The documentation was useless, and I couldn't find any code example. Apparently, Microsoft thought getting pictures from the camera is more important than opening a file.

The file stream has a member `ReadAsync` which I think reads the data. This method needs a buffer as a parameter and returns another buffer (???). So I create a buffer:

```
    var buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(1024 * 1024 * 10); // 10 mb should be enough for an mp3
    var resultbuffer = await filestream.ReadAsync(buffer, 1024 * 1024 * 10, Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.ReadAhead);
```

I am wondering... what happens if the file doesn't have enough bytes? I haven't seen any info in the documentation.

Now I need to calculate the hash for this file. To do that, I need to create an algorithm object...

```
    var alg = Windows.Security.Criptography.Core.HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("md5");
    var hashbuff = alg.HashData(resultbuffer);

    // Cleanup
    filestream.Dispose();
```

I also considered reading the file in chunks, but how can I calculate the hash like that? I looked everywhere in the documentation and found nothing about this. Could it be the CryptographicHash class type with it's 'append' method?

Now I have another issue. How can I get the data from that weird buffer thing to a byte array? The IBuffer class doesn't have any 'GetData' member, and the documentation, again, is useless.

So all I could do now is wonder about the mysteries of the universe...

```
    // ???
}
```

So the question is... how can I do this? I am completely confused, and I wonder why did Microsoft choose to make reading a file so... so... so... impossible! Even in Assembly I could figure it out easier than.... this thing.

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703816/how-to-read-file-metro-winrt/12704209#12704209

Comment: Check out the [Windows 8 special edition of MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee310108.aspx). There are a lot of useful examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinRT or Windows Runtime should not be confused with .NET as it is not .NET. WinRT has access to only a subset of the Win32 API but not to everything like the .NET is. Here is a pretty good article on what are the [rules and restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime#Restrictions_and_rules) in WinRT.

The WinRT in general does not have access to the file system. It works with *capabilities* and you can allow *file access capability* but this would restrict your app's access only to certain areas. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432876/Windows-8-The-Right-Way-to-Read-Write-Files-in-Win) is a good example of how do to file access via WinRT.