# file IO and preprocessors in Windows runtime component

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am new to using C#. I am creating a windows Runtime Component in C# using Visual Studio 2012.
I want to use File operations like write and read.
normal syntax of using file IO (The one where we use in normal form application) like:

```
String text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@actualOutputFileName);
```

doesn't seem to work. I have aslo tried using preprocessors like `#ifdef`. Those don't work either. Can anyone provide me link where i can read about these stuff. I have referred this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301.aspx

The closest I have come across is this piece of code that is compatible with windows store apps:

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("id.txt");
                liveid = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
```

Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try reading this link - it should have some information in that you can use. [Quickstart: Reading and writing a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758325.aspx)

Comment: For the file reading, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703816/how-to-read-file-metro-winrt/12704209#12704209

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me why the Normal IO (System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@actualOutputFileName)) doesn't work? @matthew Watson

Comment: It's because WRC apps are like browser apps that run in a sandbox (Android apps are like that too). WRC Applications aren't allowed to write files outside their own special file store.

Comment: is it possible to make it synchronous? I mean can we do it manually?

@Matthew Watson

Comment: @Vignesh_dino Well if you call .Wait() on the returned task it will block on the Wait() (i.e. become a synchronous call)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft are forcing Windows Store app developers to do all I/O asynchronously, so that the UI is not blocked by slow synchronous I/O. The synchronous I/O methods are **all** banned.

For `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`, Microsoft [suggest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx#IO) using `Windows.Storage.PathIO.ReadTextAsync`.

In C#, to do conditional compilation, you use `#if`.